# What's an escape character

Tags: regex, r, reserved-words

I’m taking a course online to get familiar with R. I’m having some difficulty/confusion when completing one of the exercises.

```
emails <- c("john.doe@ivyleague.edu", "education@world.gov", "dalai.lama@peace.org", "invalid.edu", "quant@bigdatacollege.edu", "cookie.monster@sesame.tv")

**hits <- grep(pattern = "@.*\\.edu$", x = emails)**
```

Can anyone kindly break-down (explain) the part of the code, which is in quotation ("@.*\.edu$")? Especially, I don’t understand the purpose of backlash? After some research, it came to my knowledge that "\" is a escape character. But, I don't understand for what purpose is it used in aforementioned (bolded)code. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: In a regular expression, the dot character, `.`, has special meaning. When  you want to refer, literally, to the dot character in the pattern you're trying to match, you use an escape character to let the regular expression parser know that you're literally referring to a dot and not the dot character it knows (which is used to represent any character).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular expression that is looking to match on a few specific elements of an email address. When you escape something in a regex expression, it's because there are reserved characters that you want to match but can't use without a little formatting. Some common reserved characters are .*[(])

So in your expression here is a breakdown of what's happening.

```
@ matches the character '@' literally

.* matches any character (except newline)

\. matches the character '.' literally

edu matches the characters 'edu' literally (case sensitive)

$ asserts position at end of the string
```

You can use one of the many regex testers available online to experiment with these things more. [Here's](https://regex101.com/) a good one